# How to apply show less and show more on cells of a reactive table in meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, reactive

```
document_table_Settings : function ()
{
    return{
        rowsPerPage: 5,
        showNavigation: 'auto',
        showColumnToggles: false,
        fields: [
            {key: 'para',label: 'Para',sortable: false},
            {key: 'desc', label: 'Description',sortable: false},
            {
                key: 'rowId', label: 'Delete',sortable: false, fn: function (rowId, object) {
                var html = "<button  name='Del' id=" + rowId + " class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button>"
                return new Spacebars.SafeString(html);
            }
          },
          {
              key: 'rowId', label: 'Edit',sortable: false, fn: function (rowId, object) {
              var html = "<button  name='edit' id=" + rowId + " class='btn btn-warning'>Edit</button>"
              return new Spacebars.SafeString(html);
            }
          }

        ]
    };
}
```

I want to show description entries having show more and show less feature .As the description is long enough. so after 100 character it shows button to toggle.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to only show the first 100 characters of the 'Description' column in the Reactive Table and then add some mechanism so that the user can click or rollover to see the entire 'Description' text.

There are a few ways to achieve this and I have provided two options below (in order of simplicity).

1. For a low tech rollover option, truncate the text to only show the first 100 characters, add an ellipsis (...) to the end of your text, then use the `title` property in a `span` element to show the full text on rollover.

First you will need to define a 'truncate' Template helper (I would make this a global helper so that you can use anywhere in your app).

```
Template.registerHelper('truncate', function(strValue, length) {
  var len = DEFAULT_TRUNCATE_LENGTH;
  var truncatedString = strValue;

  if (length && length instanceof Number) {
    len = length;
  }

  if (strValue.length > len) {
    truncatedString = strValue.substr(1, len) + "...";
  }

  return truncatedString;
});
```

Then create a new Template for the column.

```
<template name="field_description">
  <span title="{{data.description}}">{{truncate data.description}}</span>
</template>
```

And finally, change your Reactive Table configuration to use a Template.

```
fields: [
  ...,
  { key: 'desc', label: 'Description', tmpl: Template.field_description }
  ...,
];
```

2. For a slightly more complicated option, you can take a similar approach but add a clickable link that would show more or less detail.  To get it to work you have to define a few Reactive Vars, define an event handler, and change your 'Description' Template accordingly.  Here is a rough solution that should work.

Change your template like so.

```
<template name="field_description">
  <span>{{truncatedDescription}} 
    {{#if showLink}} 
      <a href="#" class="js-more-less">{{linkState}}</a>
    {{/if}}
  </span>
</template>
```

Then add the necessary logic to your field_description template (including an event handler).

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';

import './field-description.html';

Template.field_descirption.onCreated(function() {
  const MAX_LENGTH = 100;
  this.description = new ReactiveVar(Template.currentData().description);
  this.showMore = new ReactiveVar(true);

  if (this.description.get().length > MAX_LENGTH) {
    this.description.set(Template.currentData().description.substr(1, MAX_LENGTH));
  }

  this.showLink = () => {
    return Template.currentData().description.length > MAX_LENGTH;
  };

  this.toggleTruncate = () => {
    if (this.showMore.get()) {
      this.description.set(Template.currentData().description);
      this.showMore.set(false);
    } else {
      this.description.set(Template.currentData().description.substr(1, MAX_LENGTH));
      this.showMore.set(true);
    }
  };
});

Template.field_descirption.helpers({
  truncatedDescription: function() {
    return Template.instance().description.get();
  },

  showLink: function() {
    return Template.instance().showLink();
  },

  linkState: function() {
    if (Template.instance().showMore.get()) {
      return 'show more';
    } else {
      return 'show less';
    }
  };
});

Template.field_descirption.events({
  'click .js-more-less'(event, instance) {
    instance.toggleTruncate();
  },
});
```

Lastly, make sure your Reactive Table config is still setup to use a Template for the field.

```
fields: [
  ...,
  { key: 'desc', label: 'Description', tmpl: Template.field_description }
  ...,
];
```

Note that the second option makes use of Meteor's Reactivity to solve the problem.  Let me know if you need additional explanation on how the 2nd solution works.

That should do it!

Comment: I have tried your first suggestion and somewhat made my problem solve.
If you provide second technique it will be better for me in future.

Comment: @RishabhJain Did you try the 2nd approach already? I already detailed how to do it in my answer.